# Requesting long PHP scripts with AJAX

Tags: php

I'm building a website which loads dynamically from a SQL database. To do that, I've created a PHP file that handles ALL AJAX and Post and Get requests (and every page has a couple of `php include`).

The PHP is not very long yet (250 lines), but it could get much longer eventually.
Everything is wrapped in `<?php **** ?>` tags, and is clearly and methodically composed of `switch` and `case`. So I only need a couple of lines each time.

My question is: Does *every* `include` request load/download *all* the file, or just the corresponding part? Rephrasing, will a hypothetically 10,000 line long script slow down *the browser*, or just the response time from the server?

I have concerns about all this.

Thanks in advance.

PS: This idea of unifying `sql` requests comes from a computer engineer friend that's always insisting on [Multititer Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Comment: If you're concerned about performance then check-out the free caching mechanisms available to you. I use Wincache for OPCache, File Cache, Session Cache, and User Cache. User Cache allows you to cache custom output with `key => value` pairs. So if you have some process that takes a lot of time/CPU then think about caching its output for whatever time frame so your server doesn't have to do all the calculations every page load. Even just using Wincache/APC/Memcached for OPCache will speed up your application since the PHP files don't need to be turned into bit code every load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `include` a file, the entire files contents are inserted/executed into the script at that point.  Depending on what is going on with the includes, you could be slowing down the response if you are including files that are not necessary for the response.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Yes, but it consists only in a series of switch cases, so only a tiny part of the code is actually executed.
As Jasper said, it would be great to avoid converting the PHP to bits at every request...
But since all the php is a script itself `<?php ?>`, and it's server side, is it really 'inserted' in the browser? So I only have to check out for long time server response, and not browser efficiency. Is that right?

Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: The php isn't inserted in the browser, the browser only sees the html that the php generates.
For your second question, yes.  You would want to watch for a long server response.

Answer (score 0):

I have a great solution! (And this was my own question)

Instead o parsing a variable `$option` to enter a `switch case case case .... case case endswitch` I thought I could just split the PHP into a lot of different PHP's with the name of their corresponding case.

So, instead of using `case('sports')`, I will now use a `<?php include('some_folder/'.$option.'.php');?>` which will avoid converting to binary the whole file every time is called.

Since `PHP` is processed on the server, the included file will come all along and it will just have to deal with 20 lines of code instead of 400 (and, eventually, many more).

Definitively, thanks